# node streams promise error handling

Tags: node.js, error-handling, stream, promise

I have the code like this:

```
let generateSmth = function(len, j, stream, headers) {

    len--;
    j++;

    if (len === 0) {
        stream.write(headers.map(function(v) {return v + '_' + j;}));
        stream.end();
    } else {
        if (stream.write(headers.map(function(v) {return v + '_' + j;}))) {
            generateSmth(len, j, stream, headers);
        } else {
            stream.once('drain', ()=>{generateSmth(len, j, stream, headers)});
        }
    }
};
const fs = require('fs'),
      myStream = fs.createWriteStream('test.txt');
let myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    try {
        generateSmth(10000, 0, ()=>{
            resolve(()=>{

            });
        }, myStream);
    } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
    }
});
```

I have learned that try/catch is not appropriate way to catch error in generateSmth function. But I can't understand how to catch error if I use streams in my function?
Could anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: A tip, explain what you want to do with your code, and what it's purpose is instead of just pasting a block of code that we have to kind of guess why it's there. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I need to write to a file about 10000 rows generated by my function generateSmth. Also I should use Promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your Promise constructor add the following:

```
myStream.on('error', reject)
```